# Getting a callback from getJSON regardless of success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I need to handle a potentially buggy CGI interpretter.  I need to get some type of callback from a `getJSON` call in all circumstances.  That includes bogus parameters sent to the `testIt` function (see below) and the CGI sending a bogus response.  I thought wrapping the whole thing in a try/catch to handle the first case and adding a .done to handle the second would do the job.  But my .done doesn't get called if the CGI processor outputs an invalid response.  How can I ensure I always get a callback?

The code I am using is below.

```
function testIt() {
    try
    {
        console.log('start');
        $.getJSON(
            // URL of the server
            cgi_url,
            // pass the data
            {
                data: 'bogus',
            },
            // If the AJAX call was successful
            function() {
                console.log('worked');
            }
        )
        .done(function() {
                console.log('done');
            });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('exception');
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of done(), use always()

Comment: I was using an old versino of jquery that didn't support .always().  Upgraded and it is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I ensure I always get a callback?

Use [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) to attach your handler! If you want to treat errors differently, use a [`fail` handler](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/).

```
console.log('start');
$.getJSON(cgi_url, {data: 'bogus'})
    .done(function() { // If the AJAX call was successful
        console.log('worked');
    })
    .fail(function() { // If the AJAX call encountered an error
        console.log('exception');
    })
    .always(function() { // When the AJAX call ended
        console.log('done');
    });
```

Comment: I had tried .always(), but it threw an exception.  But I just noticed I was using an older version of jquery (1.5.2).  Apparently, the .always() callback doesn't work in that version.  I upgraded and it is working.  Thanks!